# Laravel search with localization

Tags: laravel, search, eloquent, localization

I have a scope about searcing. Also using localization from [mcamara](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization)

Right now, when i am search something, results are coming with different languages. But i can just search with my main language. After results are came translation happening. This is related with my blade.

```
{!! $news->translate($localeCode)->title !!}
```

But main question is before the search. How can i search something with selected language. I can switch language easily. This is my search scope.

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $search) {
     $localeCode = LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale();
    return $query->translate($localeCode)->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' .$search. '%')
        ->orWhere('sub_body', 'like', '%' .$search. '%')
        ->orWhere('body', 'like', '%' .$search. '%');
}
```

Also this is my controller

```
public function index (Request $request){

    $localeCode = LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale();
    $updates = Update::latest()->take(3)->get();
    $query = $request->get('q');
    $new = $request->filled('q') ? News::search($query) : News::query();
    $new = $new->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);


    return view('frontend.news', compact('localeCode', 'updates', 'new', 'query'));
}
```

I'll be glad if anyone help. Thanks advance.

Comment: text will search based on DB, it won't translate automatically in your languages.

Comment: That's true @Webinion for I'm struggling with the same thing at the moment. To make a website multilang it is necessary to adapt the table big time. No other way.